# Spock: how to ignore or skip certian case?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

With Spock, assume some function that will return unexpectable result on certian condition, how to match part of the result and ignore others?

```
int[] randomOnCondition(int input) {
    def output = input == 1 ? Random.newInstance().nextInt() : input
    [input, output]
}

def test() {
    expect:
    randomOnCondition(input) == output as int[]

    where:
    input || output
    2     || [2, 2]
    1     || [1, _]   //how to match part of the result and ignore others?
}
```

updated

```
def test() {
    expect:
    Integer[] output = randomOnCondition(input)
    output[0] == output0
    output[1] == output1

    where:
    input || output0 | output1
    2     || 2       | 2
    1     || 1       | _  //for somecase , can it skip assert?
}
```

Seems no solution, I should split the case into two

Comment: you can just use regular code as assertions in the `expect` part. So e.g. `randomOnCondition(input)[0] == expected` and change the expected/output part to an int

Comment: Thank you @OnnoRouast, you give me the first reply! I've updated the question. In this issue, I need also check the second result. assert only the first one is not enough. any sugguest?

Comment: for cases when you don't need validation you can e.g. pass `null` for output1, and then only check the condition in a conditional block `if (output1) { x == y }` . Also, you only need one `|` separator, not two!
You can use a `given:` ... `then:` block instead of `expect:`, and if you want to define variables inside, do so in the `given` block.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test here? Does the second output have to be there or not? As in "it must be there, but it could be anything" or "sometimes there only is one output"?

Comment: Don't make a simple thing complicated. Split the method because there clearly are two different cases to test: one case is to check both values, the other case is to selectively check only one value. Make sure the feature methods have nice names explaining what they do and be happy with the result (as in "readable code").

Comment: @cfrick For my case there will be multiple properties in an output, when input=2, all the output properties values are predictable and can use "assert" here. but on input=1, some properties are "unpredictable". I'm trying to write predictable and unpredictable values in a same "where" clause and try to ignore those "unpredictable" values.

Comment: +1 for splitting the test.  If it's a random data or order problem, then you are better off testing the two different things and test for the different properties.  E.g. even if unpredictable, maybe the value must be in a range, or the amount of other results must be a fixed value, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I explained in my previous comment:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q63355662

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class SeparateCasesTest extends Specification {
  int[] randomOnCondition(int input) {
    def output = input % 2 ? Random.newInstance().nextInt() : input
    [input, output]
  }

  @Unroll
  def "predictable output for input #input"() {
    expect:
    randomOnCondition(input) == output

    where:
    input || output
    2     || [2, 2]
    4     || [4, 4]
    6     || [6, 6]
  }

  @Unroll
  def "partly unpredictable output for input #input"() {
    expect:
    randomOnCondition(input)[0] == firstOutputElement

    where:
    input || firstOutputElement
    1     || 1
    3     || 3
    5     || 5
  }
}
```

---

**Update:** Somewhat unrelated to your question, but a way to streamline your test if the output really contains input values:

```groovy
  @Unroll
  def "predictable output for input #input"() {
    expect:
    randomOnCondition(input) == [input, input]

    where:
    input << [2, 4, 6]
  }

  @Unroll
  def "partly unpredictable output for input #input"() {
    expect:
    randomOnCondition(input)[0] == input

    where:
    input << [1, 3, 5]
  }
```

Comment: The usual way to thank people on SO is to accept an answer by clicking on the grey check mark beside it and thus close the question. So please do that if you think that my answer is correct. Thank you very much.